# Named queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nosql, kibana

I need to search through a database with 3 keywords(3 queries), and I need to tell the user which of the keywords (query) that gave a result.
I've been looking into Named Queries as a possible solution.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html

I was wondering if it is possible to apply named queries to a nested query?

According to the documentation:

> The search response will include for each hit the matched_queries it
>   matched on.

So I tried with just one easy query to see how it works, I got a result, but no "matched_queries". Did I do something wrong?

This is my query in Kibana: (Im not using actual name)

```
GET database/document/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "first_path",
            "query": {
                "nested" : {
                    "path" :  "second_path",
                    "query" :  {
                       "match": {
                           "match_field": {
                           "query": "First query",
                           "_name" : "query"
                       }
                    }
                } 
               }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DId you manage to solve the problem? I think you are missing "name" query inside `match_field`. SO `match_field` => `name` => [`query`, `_name`]. Have a look here: https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-named-queries

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see in

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html

> The search response will include for each hit the matched_queries it
>   matched on. The tagging of queries and filters only make sense for the
>   bool query.

It looks like you should use "bool" query in your inner-most query:

```
   .
   .
   .
   "query" : {
     "bool": {
       "should" {
        …
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: This solution seems to be not working for nested queries.